# Geany - what's the shortcut for inserting curly brackets?

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, geany

As it is written above. I came across that shortcut a few times but unfortunately I can't recall it because I found it not very useful. Now I've changed my mind and I was searching through web but without any success. Could somebody help me, please?

Comment: The shortcut for inserting an opening curly bracket is Shift+[, for closing curly bracket is Shift+] :)

Comment: Maybe OP wants autocompletion?

Answer (score 1):

Your keyboard has curly brackets on it already.  If it's like most, they'll be above the square brackets `[` and `]`.  So you press `Shift`+`[` to get `{`.

If you wanted to be able to turn on **automatic insertion** of curly braces, this question may be relevant:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925282/is-there-an-auto-close-curly-brackets-plugin-for-the-geany-ide

Basically, you go to [Preferences, then Completions](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#editor-completions-preferences), and the options are under **Auto-close quotes and brackets**.